# How to get user's mail address with Identity and ASP.Net Core

Tags: asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-1.0

I'm using ASP.NET Core and ASP.NET Identity.

I'm trying to get user's mail address (not the current user one).

For the current user, I have no trouble, I did this and it's working :

```
private Task<ApplicationUser> GetCurrentUserAsync() => _userManager.GetUserAsync(HttpContext.User);
```

And in my Controller's method:

```
ApplicationUser curUser = await GetCurrentUserAsync();
string mail = curUser.Email;
```

It's working, but I want another user's mail address too, from his identifier.

How can I do that ?

Comment: User's mail addresses are not encrypted in DB so I made my custom service to read email of users and it's working but I'm sure there is a clean way to do this using Identity's user manager ...

Comment: Usermanager has `FindByIdAsync` method. `var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync("userId");
            var userEmail = user.Email;`

Comment: @kodikotrifis thank's

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Add claim:

```
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim("ClaimName",
        model.User.ProfileImageUrl));
        var parincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
        await HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, parincipal);
```

Step 2: Get User in Layout page:

```
 <img src="@User.FindFirst("ClaimName").Value"  alt="" />
```

> This example for get user profile image from AspNetUsers table to show image in layout page using claim